# How to integrate Yii & WHMCS Api with ps-yii-extensions

Tags: yii, whmcs

Is there any method to integrate Yii Framework & the billing WHMCS with the extensions ps-yii-extensions?

[This is a link](https://code.google.com/p/ps-yii-extensions/wiki/HowToConnectWithTwitterFromYii) of the tutorial of twitter API, does it function with the WHMCS API?